# BlazeDs java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float

Tags: java, actionscript-3, apache-flex, jakarta-ee, blazeds

Hello I'm implementing some tests through an AMF connection to test the performaces 
of a service deployed to a wildfly8 application server instance, that saves a complex type of entity.
This entity contains a field like:

```
  private Quantity<Float> quantity = null;
```

When Quantity is an object.

```
public class Quantity<T extends Number> implements Serializable
```

When this field is valued it is raised an exception:

```
javax.ejb.EJBTransactionRolledbackException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.handleInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:163)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.invokeInCallerTx(CMTTxInterceptor.java:253)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.required(CMTTxInterceptor.java:342)
at org.jboss.as.ejb3.tx.CMTTxInterceptor.processInvocation(CMTTxInterceptor.java:239)
at org.jboss.invocation.InterceptorContext.proceed(InterceptorContext.java:309)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.Float
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.java.FloatTypeDescriptor.unwrap(FloatTypeDescriptor.java:36)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.RealTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(RealTypeDescriptor.java:64)
at org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
at org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
at org.hibernate.type.ComponentType.nullSafeSet(ComponentType.java:367)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3121)
at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3581)`
```

As suggested in this link (http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/index.php/custom-type-masrhaller-in-blazeds) I tried to override the method ASTranslator.convert (Object source, Class desiredClass) using a NumberDecoder to solve a problem known in BlazeDS, but nothing changed.

The problem is that Flex java wrapper classes (i.e. Float, Double, Long, Integer, Short, Byte, BigDecimal and BigInteger) and simple type (i.e. float, double, long, int, short, byte) are marshaled into AS3 Number type.

Comment: I'm no Java expert but you are sure that the **null** is NOT causing a problem? Can it not be `private Quantity<Float> quantity = 0;`? Otherwise using `null` is just like saying **undefined** or **non-existant**..

Comment: Quantity is an object. It can't be 0.

Comment: Solution:  Add a children to Quantity<T extends Number> that have a real implementation of T (e.g. QuantityOfFloat extends Quantity<Float>). 
In this case BlaseDs has a real implementation of Number not an Object.

Comment: You should post the solution as an actual answer. That way  the question does not remain with "0 answers" in search. No one will know the comments alone has a solution.